# How do I configure capistrano to use my rvm version of Ruby

Tags: ruby, capistrano, rvm

Does anybody know how I can tell [capistrano](http://www.capify.org/index.php/Capistrano) to use my default [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) version of ruby for on the server I am pushing to. It insists on using the system version.

Is it even possible?

Comment: I am not putting this in an answer because I am hoping someone else *really* knows how to do this, but it seems from my quick research you will need to alter the `PATH` variable to include the path to your RVM ruby before the default one: http://kete.net.nz/documentation/topics/show/240-configuring-sudo-path-in-capistrano-deployments

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`rvm-capistrano` gem](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm-capistrano)  is the best way to go.

[Link to the official detailed usage of that gem](https://rvm.io/integration/capistrano/#gem). From that I am guessing this will get the local version of Ruby:

```
set :rvm_ruby_string, ENV['GEM_HOME'].gsub(/.*\//,"") # Read from local system
```

Comment: I think the more official way is `set :rvm_ruby_string, :local`

Comment: In capistrano3, using [capistrano-rvm](https://github.com/capistrano/rvm), use something like:   
`set :rvm_ruby_version, 'jruby-1.7.13'`

Answer (score 37):

You have two options:

1. Enable .ssh environment variables using the `PermitUserEnvironment` option in your ssh configuration file
2. Use the capistrano `:default_environment` setting

For the second option, simply add the following line in your deploy.rb file

```
set :default_environment, { 
  'PATH' => "/path/to/.rvm/ree-1.8.7-2009.10/bin:/path/to/.rvm/gems/ree/1.8.7/bin:/path/to/.rvm/bin:$PATH",
  'RUBY_VERSION' => 'ruby 1.8.7',
  'GEM_HOME' => '/path/to/.rvm/gems/ree/1.8.7',
  'GEM_PATH' => '/path/to/.rvm/gems/ree/1.8.7' 
}
```

To get the accurate locations have a look at `cat ~/.rvm/default`

Comment: I think the first PATH setting should be `path/to/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7`
My RVM installation uses `rubies` anyway as the directory that ruby is actually isntalled

Comment: thank you, I found this after way too much time beating my head against the wall.

Comment: This will also work for non-rvm server installations that use a non-standard location for ruby (like REE installed in `/opt` for example). To get the right paths in this case, use `which ruby` and `gem environment`. You may not need to set `GEM_HOME`.

Answer (score 23):

If your rvm version is recent on both development and production machines add this to your deploy.rb:

```
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.2@yourapp' # you probably have this already
set :rvm_type, :user # this is the money config, it defaults to :system
```

Comment: For this why does it matter if rvm is on my dev machine?  Shouldn't it only matter if it is on the production machien?

Answer (score 7):

See http://rvm.io/integration/capistrano/.
"Integration via the rvm capistrano plugin" looks like a winner.

And http://rvm.io/deployment/

Comment: +1 for the page http://rvm.io/integration/capistrano/ and the use of the `rvm-capistrano` gem

Answer (score 1):

I found out the easiest way is to add the version you want. Just add

`ruby-2.5.0`

string (or the version you want) into .ruby-version in the root folder. No need to configure deploy.rb or some rather hacky solutions.

Answer (score 0):

For rbenv, don't forget to change `set :rbenv_ruby, "3.0.0"` in `Capfile` :)