# Rvm - Capistrano integration on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm, capistrano

I am trying to properly use Capistrano and RVM in order to deploy my Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 application to the remote machine that is running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I read the "[How do I configure capistrano to use my rvm version of Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978797/how-do-i-configure-capistrano-to-use-my-rvm-version-of-ruby)" question/answer and the "[Using RVM rubies with Capistrano](http://beginrescueend.com/integration/capistrano/)" official documentation, but I have still some issues relating to the *Rvm - Capistrano integration*.

For example, relating to the *integration via the rvm capistrano plugin* (see the official documentation for more information), **what I have to make exactly** (since I didn't understand *where* and *how* to put the related code)**?**

Or, relating to the *integration via `:default_environment`* (see the official documentation for more information), you should properly state the following code in the `deploy.rb` file:

```
set :default_environment, {
  'PATH'         => "/path/to/.rvm/gems/ree/1.8.7/bin:/path/to/.rvm/bin:/path/to/.rvm/ree-1.8.7-2009.10/bin:$PATH",
  'RUBY_VERSION' => 'ruby 1.8.7',
  'GEM_HOME'     => '/path/to/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01',
  'GEM_PATH'     => '/path/to/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01',
  'BUNDLE_PATH'  => '/path/to/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.01'  # If you are using bundler.
}
```

**What those paths refer to?** How can I retrieve path values running Linux Ubuntu?

And finally, what integration type do you advice to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly ensure that rvm installed on the machine.

See [RVM Installation Instructions](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)
or [RVM on Ubuntu 10.04](http://elouisyoung.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/rvm-on-ubuntu-1004.html) if rvm isn't installed.

Then find where rvm is installed to, this can be done either using the `find` or `locate` commands.

E.g.

`find / -iname *rvm`

or

`locate rvm`

In the output of these commands you will see something that looks like /somedirectory/someotherdirectory/.rvm/gees/somethingelse.

The `/somedirectory/someotherdirectory/` is what you would replace `/path/to/` with in `deploy.rb` or replace `ENV['rvm_path']` in the unshift command in the documentation of the first option at [Using RVM rubies with Capistrano](http://beginrescueend.com/integration/capistrano/).

The paths in the `deploy.rb` are

`/path/to/.rvm` RVM Installation Path

`'PATH'` is the binary path that is used to call the rvm binary from.

See [here](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html) for more information on PATH.

`GEM_HOME` is the home directory of the Gem.

See [here](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/1) for more information on Gems.

`'GEM_PATH'` is the PATH of the Gem.

`'BUNDLE_PATH'` is the PATH of the Bundle.

See [here](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html) for more information on Bundles and Bundler.

Comment: It seams that I solved this problem. However, now I get another error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703680/rvm-capistrano-and-delayedjob-the-you-need-to-add-gem-daemons-to-your-gemfi

Answer (score 0):

I have created example project for rvm/capistrano integration https://github.com/mpapis/ad

and you can see how easy it was to create deployment script here https://github.com/mpapis/ad/blob/master/config/deploy.rb

most important is to visit the server before deployment and install the proper ruby.

I will also add a new tasks to integration to install rvm/ruby -> https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/829

Comment: It seams that I solved this problem. However, now I get another error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703680/rvm-capistrano-and-delayedjob-the-you-need-to-add-gem-daemons-to-your-gemfi