# How to solve the "You need to add gem 'daemons' to your Gemfile if you wish to use it" error in production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, capistrano, delayed-job

I am trying to properly use Capistrano and RVM in order to deploy my Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 application to the remote machine that is running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. It *seams* that I solved my previous problem related to the "[Rvm - Capistrano integration on Linux Ubuntu](http://Rvm%20-%20Capistrano%20integration%20on%20Linux%20Ubuntu)". However, on deploying I get the following error related to the DelayedJob gem:

```
    ...
  * executing "cd /srv/www/<APP_NAME>/releases/20120314135318 && bundle install"
    servers: ["<DOMAIN>"]
    [<DOMAIN>] executing command
    [<DOMAIN>] rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.3-p125' -c 'cd /srv/www/<APP_NAME>/releases/20120314135318 && bundle install'     ** [out :: <DOMAIN>] Using rake (0.9.2.2)
 ** [out :: <DOMAIN>] Using builder (3.0.0)
    ...
 ** [out :: <DOMAIN>] Using daemons (1.1.8)
 ** [out :: <DOMAIN>] Using delayed_job (3.0.1)
 ** [out :: <DOMAIN>] Using delayed_job_active_record (0.3.2)
    ...
 ** [out :: <DOMAIN>] Your bundle is complete! It was installed into /srv/www/<APP_NAME>/shared/bundle
    ...
    [<DOMAIN>] executing command
    [<DOMAIN>] rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.3-p125' -c 'cd /srv/www/<APP_NAME>/current;  RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop'
*** [err :: <DOMAIN>] /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/command.rb:4:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
*** [err :: <DOMAIN>] :
*** [err :: <DOMAIN>] You need to add gem 'daemons' to your Gemfile if you wish to use it.
*** [err :: <DOMAIN>] (
*** [err :: <DOMAIN>] RuntimeError
*** [err :: <DOMAIN>] )
*** [err :: <DOMAIN>] from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/delayed_job-3.0.1/lib/delayed/command.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
*** [err :: <DOMAIN>] from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
*** [err :: <DOMAIN>] from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
*** [err :: <DOMAIN>] from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
*** [err :: <DOMAIN>] from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
*** [err :: <DOMAIN>] from script/delayed_job:4:in `<main>'
    command finished in 7512ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
    ...

failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.3-p125' -c 'cd /srv/www/<APP_NAME>/releases && tar xzf /tmp/20120314140345.tar.gz && rm /tmp/20120314140345.tar.gz'" on <DOMAIN>
```

Even if the error explanation is "You need to add gem 'daemons' to your Gemfile if you wish to use it", I already added the `daemons` gem to my `Gemfile` (from the above output you can even note that I am "Using daemons (1.1.8)"):

```
...
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'daemons'
...
```

So, **what is the problem? How can I solve that?**

---

In my `deploy.rb` file I have:

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
require 'rvm/capistrano'
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.3-p125'
set :rvm_type, :user
require 'bundler/capistrano'
...
```

*P.S.*: Terminal window output:

```
 $ ruby -v
 > ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [i686-linux]
 $ which ruby
 > /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
```

Comment: the script/delayed_job is yours or not ? It require bundler inside ?

Comment: @shingara - What do you mean with "is yours or not"? With the "script/delayed_job" what file are you referring to? However, in the above code/output is all "mine" (that is, code and outputs are "real"/"what I am using and getting").

Comment: in log you past the command failed is : `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop` I want to know if this script is generate or you create it.

Comment: @shingara - That output refers to DelayedJob workers. It is generated by running `"cd #{current_path}; #{try_sudo} RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job -n 2 start"` code present in the `config/deploy.rb` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run script/delayed_job with bundler: 
`bundle exec script/delayed_job start`

Comment: Your code doesn't work and I get "`bundler: command not found: RAILS_ENV=production - Install missing gem executables with 'bundle install'`" (of course I try to run `bundle install` on the server machine but it doesn't update any gem since all those are already updated). I also tried to use "`bundle exec rake script/delayed_job stop`, but I get this error: `rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'stop'`".

Comment: 1- The delayed_job script is not a rake task, so of course rake will not work. 2- It looks like you modified my command incorrectly. Try moving the env to the front like `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec script/delayed_job start`. Please note that this must be run from the application root dir.

Comment: Dont forget to make the script/delayed_job file executable:    chmod +x script/delayed_job