# Error deploying with cap deploy when using gem paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, capistrano

I am using the gem [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and now I wanted to deploy my app to the server using capistrano, but when run `cap deploy` I get the following message at the end:

```
 * executing "cd /home/administrator/myApp/releases/20120506165329 && bundle install --gemfile /home/administrat
or/myApp/releases/20120506165329/Gemfile --path /home/administrator/myApp/shared/bundle --deployment --qui
et --without development test"
    servers: ["myserver.com"]
    [myserver.com] executing command
 ** [out :: myserver.com] Gem::InstallError: paperclip requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
 ** [out :: myserver.com] An error occured while installing paperclip (3.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
 ** [out :: myserver.com] Make sure that `gem install paperclip -v '3.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
    command finished in 66362ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/administrator/myApp/releases/20120506165329; true"
    servers: ["myserver.com"]
    [myserver.com] executing command
    command finished in 66ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/administrator/myApp/releases/20120506165329 && bundle install --gemfile /home/administra
tor/myApp/releases/20120506165329/Gemfile --path /home/administrator/myApp/shared/bundle --deployment --qu
iet --without development test'" on myserver.com
```

I have checked the version of Ruby in my server and I got:

```
$ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
```

I have also intalled the gem manually in the server by running

```
gem install paperclip -v '3.0.3'
...
Successfully installed paperclip-3.0.3
```

and ran `cap deploy` again, but the same message showed up

how can I deploy my app?

thanks you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed by setting de default environments of capistrano as suggested in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978797/how-do-i-configure-capistrano-to-use-my-rvm-version-of-ruby)

I can now deploy with capistrano (although my system ruby is still using ruby 1.8.7 so the gem paperclip does not get installed properly, you can find this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474854/setting-servers-system-ruby-version))