# rubygems-bundler gem load error on capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler

I'm getting the following error when I try to deploy my project using capistrano:

```
Gem::LoadError: Could not find 'rubygems-bundler' (>= 0) among 69 total gem(s)
An error occured while installing cocaine (0.3.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install cocaine -v '0.3.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

now a `gem list | grep cocaine` says `cocaine (0.4.2, 0.3.2, 0.2.1)` 
and a `gem list | grep rubygems-bundler` says `rubygems-bundler (1.0.2)` so i know the gems are installed. 
`which ruby` says `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby`

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you tried those commands after `cap shell`?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1979241/1197775

Comment: Are you running gem list, etc. on your local machine or on the remote one?  The gems need to be installed on the remote machine. See the comments above by juanpastas above.

Comment: @juanpastas & josh, yes those commands were run on the remote machine

Comment: how are you running those commands in remote machine? is different to use `ssh ...` and use `cap shell`, the latter uses capistrano evnironment configuration, first one uses system environment configuration.

Comment: @juanpastas thanks for the clarification. Okay I reran the above commands using cap shell and the results where the same, both the existence of the gems in question and using the ruby version at the same location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, was able to solve my own problem. Turns out rubygems-bundler is not what I thought it was and had accidentally installed it in a previously attempt to solve another problem.

I solved this issue by:

```
rubygems-bundler-uninstaller
gem uninstall rubygems-bundler
rvm all-gemsets do gem uninstall --all --executables rubygems-bundler
```

No idea what caused it, but i was able to deploy just fine afterwards.

Hope that helps someone else!